# create-react-app is no longer working in my computer anymore

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, tar, npx

create-react-app is no longer working on my computer

> A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
> Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
> You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again

I obviously try the `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` command, but it didn't work.

I tried to update npx, npm, clear cache on npx, on npm, I tried installing the latest version of the create-react-app. nothing worked so far.

```
npm install create-react-app@latest
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

added 51 packages, removed 6 packages, changed 12 packages, and audited 68 packages in 2s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I tried uninstalling tar, the exact same message as before appears.

Comment: `npx create-react-app my-app` is how docs today suggested to create new app. probably on your system there's an old version of react

Comment: I had this, global uninstall command not fixing, had to manually hunt down the settings files. Can't remember where they were, somewhere under Windows user folder, maybe C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache or C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\npm-cache - note AppData is a hidden folder, use View menu to reveal it.

Comment: @HagaiHarari I know, that wast the command I was trying to execute in the first place

Comment: Hi @Electron I'm using a Mac, I tried to eliminate all create-react-app files from my computer by looking at them with the which command... saddly nothing was retreived, I will look for the npm-cache that you have mentioned

Comment: Thanks to both of you for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it
the command `npm install tar@6 -g`
was what I needed to properly update tar and the error disapear.
Thanks to all who took the time to help me